# Linked List Head address loops together and changes

Tags: c, linked-list

**strong text**I have created two struct, donor and read.

```
struct stored
{
    char *string;
    struct stored*link;
};

struct donor
{
    char *id;
    struct donor* link;
};
```

1 FM SA 1 1.0

2 FM SG 2 4.0

3 OM AU 1 0.5

The goal here is to read testing.txt's lines which contain lines of donation details (as shown above), save every line of string in a linked list(stored), then loop over (stored) to get the string again at every node, split the string into space-separated values, creating a struct Donor which we then store the fist index value into Donor*node ->id. When finished looping over (stored), we will have created another linked list (Donor) with all the id(1-5). The issue here is that my head1 pointer address loops together with the loop and I lose the address. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct stored Stored;
typedef struct donor Donor;

Stored *head, *current ; 
Donor *head1, *current1 ; 

void print(Stored* head){
    Stored* current_node = head;
    while(current_node!= NULL){
        printf("%s\n", current_node->id);
        current_node = current_node->link;
    }
}


int main(void){
    char line[128];
    FILE * fp;
    
    head  = current  = NULL; 
    fp = fopen("testing.txt","r");
    
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        Stored *node = malloc(sizeof(Stored));
        node->string = strdup(line);
        
        node->link = NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
            current = head = node;
        } 
        else{
            current = current->link = node;
        }
    }
    print(head);
 


    Stored*temp = head;   
    char *stemp;
    char newString[10][10];
    int j, i, ctr;
    head1  = current1  = NULL; 
    while(temp != NULL){
        stemp = temp->string ;
        j=0; ctr=0;
        for(i=0;i<=(strlen(stemp));i++){
        // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
            if(stemp[i]==' '||stemp[i]=='\0'){
                newString[ctr][j]='\0';
                ctr++;  //for next word
                j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
            }
            else{
                newString[ctr][j]=stemp[i];
                j++;
            }
        }

        Donor *node = malloc(sizeof(Donor));
        node-> id = newString[0];
        node->link = NULL;
        
        

        if(head1 == NULL){
            current1 = head1 = node;
            
        } 
        else{
            current1 = current1->link = node;
        }   

        temp = temp->link;
    }

    print(head1);
  
}
```

When use print(), which loops through given head address and return the string or id, it outputs

```
1 FM SA 1 1.0
2 FM SG 2 4.0
3 OM AU 1 0.5
4 SM DE 3 6.0
5 HS US 2 7.5

5
5
5
5
5
```

I suspect that it's this line here where during else, head1 also updates itself to the current1 address. Which when call print(head1) its id starts from 5. What am I doing wrong here?

```
if(head1 == NULL){
            current1 = head1 = node;
        } 
        else{
            current1 = current1->link = node;
        }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  Headers are missing, main ends prematurely after print,  you need to declare your structures before using them (posted separately missing, missing ; after struct donor.  Please work that out and update question.

Comment: `node-> id = newString[0]` doesn't make sense fro two reasons: First of all `newString[0]` is a an array of characters (i.e. a string) while `node->id` is a pointer to an `int`. Secondly the assignment doesn't copy the string, it only copies the *pointer* to the first element of the array. It's the same as `node->id = &newString[0][0]`. So all nodes will have the exact same pointer, and the "string" will be the last you put into `newString[0]`.

Comment: Your format string in print is wrong.  It should be ` printf("%d\n", *current_node->id)`.  Bump up the warnings on your compiler (gcc would be -Wala).

Comment: `current1 = current1->link = node` is missing a ;

Comment: You rely on a file you didn't share with us.  You can't do `print(head)` (wrong type: expects Stored * but you pass Donor * in one place).  Anyways, I am voting to close it as there a ton of issues and you need to do some work, and I don't trust the question as you supply output but code as posted never ran.

Comment: head1/current1 iterates over Donors but you declare them `Stored *head1, *current1;`

Comment: I've found the solution. It is in fact the fact that node->id = newString[0] doesn't copy the string, but the pointers address onto id. Solved with node->id = strdup(newString[0])

Comment: Hi Allan, sorry for the mess as I have been looking at this problem for the entire day. Hopefully, I have everything fixed now. Appreciate the help in pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The lesson here is to be very careful with copying pointers and not assuming it's the same with copying/storing strings.

```
node-> id = newString[0];
```

As pointed out by someone, it's the same as node->id = &newString[0][0]

```
node-> id = strdup(newString[0]);
```

This fixed everything.